# Is C++/Tk compatible with Tk 8.5?

Tags: c++, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

Since Tk 8.5, Tk started using Native Based UI components - buttons, scrollbars etc. I wonder if C++/Tk supports such Native GUIs approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, C++/Tk is based on Tk 8.4 (if it's before that then it *really* needs updating). It wouldn't in principle be that hard to adapt to 8.5, where the Ttk widgets are supported; just a matter of adding more widget definitions (and a few other commands too, so you can do things like change the theme). If it's done at all sensibly[*], that'd take you all of  a few hours for at least some of the widgets as the Ttk widgets already follow the same sorts of patterns as existing widgets; the non-widget bits might take longer, as might the wholly new widget types (notebook, treeview) as, although they follow normal Tk patterns, they still have a number of new methods.

[* I've not read the source code to C++/Tk, so I can't say for sure how easy it is. ]